# How can I switch the tuleap's interface?

Tags: tuleap

I have a problem, my Tuleap version is 7.0, but I can't access the new interface.

I want to see this:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Hwsr.png]

But my system just show me this:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHoqA.png]

I tried searching in the documentation, but nothing helped.

What do I have to do?

Answer (score 2):

You need to install tuleap-theme-flamingparrot RPM and then switch to it in your preferences (My Personal Page).

Once installed you can also update local.inc